# Is there a more efficient way to reference an int array with a string than this

Tags: java, arrays, string, variables, names

I have hundreds of small arrays each holding two ints representing an x, y coordinate on the screen.  The method passes in a string with the same name as the array holding its values. Rather than hard coding each case like this...

```
public class Main {

    int[] a = {1000, 500},
          b = {900, 400},
          c = {800, 300};

    public method(String tile) {
        int x = 0, y = 0;

        switch(tile) {
        case "a": x = a[0]; y = a[1];
        case "b": x = b[0]; y = b[1]; 
        case "c": x = c[0]; y = c[1];
        }
    }       
}
```

How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: I think you're looking for a `Map<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>>`.

Comment: Don't forget to `break;` in each `case` section. The default is to fall through.

Comment: How are the small arrays initialized?

Comment: They're initialized by hand for now, which I know is very bad. Once I get the program in a working state, I'm going to address that.

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

```
    int[] a = {1000, 500};
    int[] b = {900, 400};
    int[] c = {800, 300};

    Map<String, int[]> stringToTile = new HashMap<>();
    stringToTile.put("a", a);
    stringToTile.put("b", b);
    stringToTile.put("c", c);

    testMethod("a", stringToTile);
    testMethod("b", stringToTile);
    testMethod("c", stringToTile);
}

public static void testMethod(String tile, Map<String, int[]> stringToTile) {
    int[] resultArray = stringToTile.get(tile);
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    if (resultArray != null) {
        x = resultArray[0];
        y = resultArray[1];
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("x: %s; y: %s", x, y));
}
```

Instead of using array, you can use object as well. I wonder if this helps.

Comment: This does help, but how can I loop through all the stringToTile.put()? Otherwise hard coding each and every one is about as much work as the case statements.